# ScrollViewChangeListener not working as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, scrollview, listener

I've defined the following code, so if an user is on top of the scrollview a swiperefreshlayout works.

```
recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener {
        if (recyclerView.scrollY == 0) {
            binding.refreshed!!.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            binding.refreshed!!.isEnabled = false
        }

    })
```

But this code only reacts first time I move the recyclerview (which, by the way is in position 0 at start, and considers it to be at position 0 when move is performed), rest of the time the listener is never fired.

What may I be doing wrong?

PD: It's possible to achieve the wanted behavior with this code:

```
   val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener {


            if (layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
                binding.refreshed!!.isEnabled = true
            } else {
                binding.refreshed!!.isEnabled = false
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this to get top position on recyclerview

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    if(layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()==0) {
         binding.refreshed!!.isEnabled = true
    }
    else {
          binding.refreshed!!.isEnabled = false
    }
```

Comment: It works by combining my code with yours as I put on edit.